# search in POP-UP LOV in APEX 5

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Good day guys,
   I just want to know if the search in a pop-up LOV in ORACLE ApEx 5 does a "query search" directly to the database or does it search in the results shown in the pop-up?TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It performs a database query.  You can verify this by using the browser's Inspect tool, Network tab and see the server request and response.

Comment: thank you @Tony Andrews. will that affect the traffic in the db since it always perform db query, given that there are multiple users using the pop-up lov?sorry for the follow up question.

Comment: Yes, but it is all perfectly normal and not something to worry about, unless your LOV query is poorly tuned and uses a lot of resources.